# Why many images are generated after the build

Tags: linux, embedded, openwrt

I'am using openwrt kernel for an embedded target. After the configuration i build the image using `make world`. In the `bin` directory i have the following [list of images generated](http://paste.ofcode.org/373TfhxGzfcMwSwXiw7FMEL) .

My Questions:

- why all this list is generated why not only one image?
- which one i should flash on my target?
- How to disable the generation of the other images (this may help to speed up the build)

Thank you

Comment: The images produced all have a target prefix - Use the one that matches your target. Once you have found out which one you need, you should be able to re-build only this by `make <target>`

Comment: @tofro You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @tofro thank you for the feedback,  i think all the binaries fit the target, they are all prefixed by `openwrt-ar71xx-generic`, ` ar71` is my board, but i don't undrestand the difference between the binaries for example: `openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tew-732br-squashfs-factory.bin ` and `openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wzr-450hp2-squashfs-tftp.bin` what does those 2 names mean and how to make a choice between them

Comment: I run `make openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin -j1 V=s ` and i got ` *** No rule to make target openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin.  Stop`

Comment: squashfs is the file system used for the installation files - tftp obviously adds network boot/install capability. Your documentation in the makefile should give a clue to that.

Comment: Moreover the `450hp2` should be the real target. I mean: `ar71xx` is the target SoC, nut not the target HW which is the board where the `Qualcomm SoC` is mounted.

Comment: I should use a uImage(because i'am using uBoot) that support rootfs over NFS so not squashfs, i'am choosing this image`openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin`, but i didn't succeed to figure out how to rebuild only this target : `make openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin` gives an error as pointed so each time time i have to clean and `make world ` again which takes a lot of time, could u please point on the Makefile to hack in order to reduce the targets.

Comment: I removed the buildroot tag - OpenWRT and Buildroot are unrelated projects.

Comment: @Arnout , could u please clarify what do you mean by "OpenWRT and Buildroot are unrelated projects"

Comment: @Mouin OpenWRT forked the Buildroot project about ten years ago, so they are two different projects. The "buildroot" tag on StackOverflow refers to the Buildroot project, not to the buildroot component of OpenWRT.

Comment: @Arnout, i'am reading buildroot documentation these days and actually there is some some differences between what i read and what actually exists in openWRT. from what you said i undrestand that there is difference between the build process in buildroot and openWRT, is that correct, could you please suggest documentation to undrestand the build process in openWRT, Thx

Comment: @Mouin I'm not very familiar with OpenWRT. I do know that their documentation is often inconsistent and out of date.The Buildroot documentation is certainly not relevant for OpenWRT. I think the only similarity is that you can do 'make menuconfig'. But, for example, 'make world' builds only a single image in Buildroot, but builds all images in OpenWRT...

Answer (score 1):

> - why all this list is generated why not only one image?

Because that is what you asked for when you "make world" - if you don't want the "world", don't ask for it!  The normal  sequence for an individual custom image would be:

```
make menuconfig
make defconfig
```

To configure your image and build it.

> - which one i should flash on my target?

The one that matches your hardware, but just installing a default configuration rather then a customised one serves little purpose perhaps.

> - How to disable the generation of the other images (this may help to speed up the build)

Well you could hack the makefile to reduce the targets, or find the name of the specific target you need and:

```
make <target>
```

Comment: thank u, 1-i'am customizing the kernel to read the command line of the bootloader and support mounting a rootfs over NFS, so i shouldn't use `make defconfig`.2- "Well you could hack the makefile", I can't figure out where exactly to do some modif so if you can point me a little bit it could be helpful. 3- I run make openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin -j1 V=s and i got ` *** No rule to make target openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin. Stop, so it's seems that the Makefiles i have don't support the build of only one target (this is only a guess)

Comment: @Mouin : Find the target 'world' and see what targets it uses.  It does not follow that you cannot use defconfig.